# Django form submit button not clickable/working

Tags: python, django

This is my code for my template

```
{% block content %}

<div class='main'>

<form method='POST' action='/social/profile/' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h3>Select an image for your profile. Max 300x300 and 1mb.</h3>
    <br/>
    <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="Profile Image" height="100px" width="100px" />

    {{ form.profileimg.errors }}
    {{ form.profileimg }}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}

    <br/>
    <h3>Enter or edit your details</h3> <br/>
    <textarea name='text' cols='50' rows='3'>{{ text }}</textarea>
    <h3>Current Workplace</h3>
    <br/>
    <input id="workplace" type="text" class="" name="workplace" value="{{ workplace }}">

    <h3>Telephone Number</h3>
    <br/>
    <input id="telephone" type="text" class="" name="telephone" value="{{ telephone }}">

    <h3>Address</h3>
    <br/>
    <textarea id="address" type="text" class="" name="address">{{ address }}</textarea>
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >

</form>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The form.profileimg is very simple with only 1 ImageField.

But the submit button is not click-able for some reason? It was working before the form.profileimg field, can I not mix Django Forms and normal html?

Browser source:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Social Network: Facemagazine</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/social/css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body class="loading">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="bg"></div>
            <div id="overlay"></div>
            <div id="main">

                <!-- Header -->
                    <header id="header" class="whitebox">
                        <h1> Facemagazine </h1>
                        <p>Worlds second best social network! </p>
                        <nav >
                            <ul>

                                <li><a class='icon' href='/social/members/?view=julian'> <h3> Home </h3> </a></li>
                                <li><a class='icon' href='/social/members/'> <h3>Members </h3> </a></li>
                                <li><a class='icon' href='/social/friends/'> <h3> Friends </h3> </a></li>
                                <li><a class='icon' href='/social/messages/'> <h3> Messages </h3> </a></li>
                                <li><a class='icon' href='/social/profile/'> <h3> Edit Profile </h3> </a></li>
                                <li><a class='icon' href='/social/logout/'> <h3> Log out </h3> </a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </nav>

                    <br>


<div class='main'>

<form method='POST' action='/social/profile/' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='kire68pdevP0JZt8gTUYSsj6Dit1cgro' />
    <h3>Select an image for your profile. Max 300x300 and 1mb.</h3>
    <br/>
    <img src="/media/profileimgs/no-img.jpg" alt="Profile Image" height="100px" width="100px" />


    <input id="id_profileimg" name="profileimg" type="file" />


    <br/>
    <h3>Enter or edit your details</h3> <br/>
    <textarea name='text' cols='50' rows='3'>Test Details</textarea>
    <h3>Current Workplace</h3>
    <br/>
    <input id="workplace" type="text" class="" name="workplace" value="Workplacee">

    <h3>Telephone Number</h3>
    <br/>
    <input id="telephone" type="text" class="" name="telephone" value="Telefon">

    <h3>Address</h3>
    <br/>
    <textarea id="address" type="text" class="" name="address">adres</textarea>
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >

</form>

</div>

                    <br>
                    </header>


                <!-- Footer -->
                    <footer id="footer">
                        <span class="copyright">&copy; Group 45</span>
                    </footer>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="/static/social/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script>
            window.onload = function() { document.body.className = ''; }
            window.ontouchmove = function() { return false; }
            window.onorientationchange = function() { document.body.scrollTop = 0; }
        </script>
    <script src="/static/social/scripts.js"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It shouldn't have anything to do with that field. When you view source through browser do you see any errors highlighted?

Comment: Post the actual source code to the page.  browser -> View Source

Comment: @JohnGordon Posted. No errors shown.

Comment: You have two inputs with type `submit` at the end of your form. Are both displaying? And is that closing header tag where it should be?

Comment: @souldeux Yes they both display, I put two because I was just checking whether it differed with a button tag or input tag. (Makes no difference)


The header tag is fine, this is just a school coursework so I didn't take much care in proper formatting but the CSS all displays as should.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say the submit button is not clickable?  Does it display?  Is it disabled (greyed out)?  It doesn't depress when clicked on?  Does clicking on it just have no effect?

Comment: @JohnGordon It doesn't depress when clicked on

Comment: copy pasted the HTML source to a new file, opened in Chrome, the submit button works. Check if any of your scripts binds to the form submit event and changes/cancels it

Comment: Okay I just discovered removing the <img> tag makes the button work again. Why could this be?

Comment: @AviahLaor I removed all js scripts and it didn't change anything. Removing the <img> however made the button work again. Why would that be?

Comment: @TheDream: copy paste the HTML, create a new file, open and submit. It works in Chorme/OSX

Comment: @AviahLaor Yes, but it doesn't work within my Django project.

Comment: @TheDream the view gets the submit request? Check with DevTools or TamperData FF. It sends something?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Problem was me being stupid with the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was the footer. The CSS was messed up so was overlaying on top of the button somehow.